# Galvanized 5V Crimp roofing screw placement with battens/counterbattens

Tags: roof, metal-roof

I am installing 5V crimp roofing over an addition to my small house. The additions's roof joins the house under a 14" eave. The main house slope is 5/12 or about 22.5 deg. The addition slope is 10 deg.

On the addition, the rafters are 16in o/c, and the roof deck is 7/16 OSB, with GAF synthetic felt.

My plan is to install 1x4 battens running up slope, and above that, run 2x4 counterbattens. The metal will screw to the counter battens using rubber-washer screws for this purpose. The metal is coming from Lowes and I do not know the manufacturer. However many manufacturers specify putting screws in the "peaks" and also , alternatively, putting them in the "flats" between the V's. There will be a vertical lap about 16" up from the bottom edge of the roof. Of course, I will order rake trim to run down the left and right edges.

The home is located in far north central Texas.

**MY QUESTIONS:**

1. Is this slope really too low for 5V Crimp?
2. Is it better to install the screws in the "peaks" or the "flats"?

[image: 5v cross section]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If 1 and 2 are really your only two questions, those will be found in the installation manual from the metal supplier.  They will have a screw location guide based on the wind speed in your area and will also specify the minimum slope allowed.  I think many metal roofs are ok even on a 2/12 slope, maybe even 1/12, but the manual will tell you for sure.

Comment: Well, that's just it ... I don't know the manufacturer. However ... I have talked to a couple of folks, and it seems that 5V crimp is the wrong tool for this job, due to the slope. I am going to look hard at standing seam, perhaps without attaching to battens and going straight to the roof deck

Comment: You can't go wrong with standing seam...IF you can afford it. I put a 5-V over my back porch and had no issues for over 15 years... however, it my case, it was not critical there be no leaks. I put the fasteners on the V-s--which I believe is the proper location. Much less rain surface for a potential leak to develop if you think about it. I am curious as to why you covered the battens with OSB. ..seems an unnecessary expense to me. I had no decking in my case--just battens.

Comment: Are you in an area that gets snow?  I’ve just never heard of that slope being a problem, but I’ve never lived in a snow area.

Comment: I have seen a few leak issues with 5v and would go with standing seam. But I am in Oregon and we do get a lot of rain here the pitch should be fine though.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to go in a different direction... I will be using standing seam metal from McElroy:

https://www.mcelroymetal.com/standing-seam-systems/medallion-lok

This offers a 1 3/4" high channel, and all hidden fasteners. I simply cannot believe that water will run over that high of a wall over 9 feet run, even in the most brutal rainstorm, and even with a 2-slope.

Snow is minimal here, we rarely get more than about an inch or so. Even then I can just get up on a ladder and sweep it (not getting on the slick wet roof of course!)

Thanks to everyone for their comments and guidance.